# monitor related problem

Tags: cpu, display, motherboard

I've got a motherboard that when powered on, doesn't send any output to the monitor. but when  connect the monitor to another motherboard, it works fine. so, it has to do with my motherboard.

I want to know the various reasons for which a motherboard wouldn't send signals to the monitor and what I could do to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you got some way of confirming that the machine is powering up correctly? Is it pingable from the network for instance?

Answer (score 1):

If the motherboard has onboard video as well as a dedicated video card, you may have the monitor plugged into the wrong port.

Onboard video may be disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: I verified, I think I've plugged the monitor into the write port. the problem is that I can't even access the BIOS.

Comment: Are you using onboard, or a dedicated card? Do you have a spare graphics card to put into the machine?

Comment: I'm using onboard card. i've never faced any difficulties before.

Answer (score 0):

If you had an oscilloscope handy, you could check the video output on your motherboard to see any of the pins were toggling... but most people don't have these lying around.

Many motherboards also support a TFT or LVDS flat panel connection.   If a user has changed the BIOS settings to use the panel connection (instead of SVGA), your motherboard may be confused.   Generally, SVGA or DVI is the default video output.   I recommend booting your PC with the default CMOS settings jumper installed, to set your BIOS back to the defaults.